# JavaScript: Iframe's width attribute change based on the available space?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to, using JavaScript, resize an iframe, so its width will be equal to real value of available space?

Setting width to 100% results in white borders around the meant iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `iframe` to cover your entire site, and don't want to use a `frameset` page, try...

#### CSS

```
html,
body {
   height: 100%;  
}   

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
     
}

iframe {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;   
   border: none;  
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Tg9jz/).

Comment: Body width? It doesn't need to change dynamically - can be "hardcoded", value in pixels. Screen resolution - may work?

Comment: @Paul I can't test Opera and IE right now, but I can confirm it works in Safari 5.0.3.